# Can tqdm be embedded to html?

Tags: python, progress-bar, bokeh, tqdm

I want to embed tqdm progressbar to html or at least print it as html tag but i can't find any documention of it. I only find how to print the progressbar in python notebook.

Is it possible to embed it in html?

Also is it possible to integrate tqdm with bokeh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tqdm progress bars can't be embedded into HTML. The progress bar in the browser should somehow communicate with Python in order to update the progress bar. [Here is one good example of how to do this in Flask.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55658488/how-to-make-a-progress-bar-on-a-web-page-for-pandas-operation)

[Bokeh has a request opened in 2017 for a progress bar that is still open](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/6556) and [here is a similar question for how to create a progress bar in Bokeh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55798378/how-do-i-create-a-loading-indicator-in-bokeh).