# Flask: Server-sent event (SSE) stream function is halted when processing input

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, html, flask

I'm working on a problem very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55658488/how-to-make-a-progress-bar-on-a-web-page-for-pandas-operation) (lots of code copied from there): Displaying a progress bar for processing an input uploaded via a html form.

HTML:

```
  <script>
  function getProgress() {
    var source = new EventSource("/progress");
    source.onmessage = function(event) {
      $('.progress-bar').css('width', event.data+'%').attr('aria-valuenow', event.data);
      $('.progress-bar-label').text(event.data+'%');

      // Event source closed after hitting 100%
      if(event.data == 100){
        source.close()
      }
    }
  }
  </script>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      ...
      <form method="POST" action="/process" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
        ...
          <input type="file" name="file">
          <input type="submit" name="upload" onclick="getProgress()" />
        </div>
      </form>

      <div class="progress" style="width: 80%; margin: 50px;">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active"
          role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%">
          <span class="progress-bar-label">0%</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

app.py:

```
@app.route('process')
def process_inputs():
    ...
    r.set("progress", progress)
    ...


@app.route('/progress')
def progress():

  def progress_stream():
    progress = r.get("progress")
    while progress < 100:
      yield "data:" + str(progress) + "\n\n"

      time.sleep(1)

  return Response(progress_stream(), mimetype='text/event-stream')
```

From my understanding, the `progress` and `process_input` functions should run simultaneously, so `progress` can get update the progress bar while the processing takes place. However, this doesn't work since `progress` is halted until ``process_input` is finished.

**How can I get these two function to run simultaneously?** I thought this would automatically be handled by Flask's `threaded` functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it's a browser issue: with Chrome it works as intended, but not with Firefox. Looks like Firefox doesn't process incoming SSEs while waiting on the POST-request (?)